# FLOPs for tf.embedding_lookup_sparse

Tags: tensorflow

When executing tf.embedding_lookup_sparse in tensorflow, are there any floating operations performed? And if so, is it possible to find the number of FLOPs carried by the operation?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the passed parameters, any number of FLOPs are performed. While the actual `array_ops.gather(...)` call does not perform FLOPs, there are a number of other places where computation may or may not occur.

- Integer ops are performed when sharding the the input tensors. (Can be either `mod` or `div`.)
- Incorporating weights (if not `None`)
- The combiner to reduce values together (can be `None`, `"sum"`, `"mean"`, or `"sqrtn"`.

You can see the implementation here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/embedding_ops.py#L203-L366